# control sprite image coordinates with variables in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, sprite, css-sprites

I want to control sprite image coordinates in css using variables..

```
background: url('sprite.png') no-repeat -123px -321px; width: 23px; height: 22px;
```

what I want is to be able to use the above line of code using variables,

```
background: url('sprite.png') no-repeat -X -Y; width: 23px; height: 22px;
```

so that I can set my X and Y on the fly.

PS: I'm trying to set length of lit stars from sprite according to my average-star-ratings which is a float number(like 3.1).
I don't want to use LESS or Sass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Javascript:

```
var yourelement = document.getElementById('yourelementsid');

yourelement.style.backgroundPosition = x + 'px ' + y + 'px';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do return the values with your server-side script with inline style:

```
<div style="background-position: <?php echo x . 'px ' . y . 'px'; ?>;"></div>
```